# How to avoid duplication of longtable setup code

Tags: tables, environments, longtable, automation

I have many longtable's in my document. Everything is the same across all the tables, except for the caption and the content (of course). How can I avoid duplicating the stuff required to set up longtable? Is this possible?

The code needed to produce one table is below. You can see there is a lot of stuff required to set up the table. I would like to avoid duplicating this stuff multiple times.

```
\begin{longtable}[h]{M{2.00in}M{0.85in}m{0.55in}m{0.55in}m{0.55in}m{0.55in}}
\caption{First Ministry in Jerusalem} \\
\toprule
Event & Location & Matt. & Mark & Luke & John  \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{First Ministry in Jerusalem (continued)} \\
    \toprule
    Event & Location & Matt. & Mark & Luke & John \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Content & Goes & Here
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. Note that you don't need to sign your message, as your (nick)name appears at its bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This goes in the preamble:

```
\newenvironment{mylongtable}[1]
 {\begin{longtable}{M{2.00in}M{0.85in}m{0.55in}m{0.55in}m{0.55in}m{0.55in}}
  \caption{#1} \\
    \toprule
    Event & Location & Matt. & Mark & Luke & John  \\
    \midrule
  \endfirsthead
    \caption{First Ministry in Jerusalem (continued)} \\
    \toprule
    Event & Location & Matt. & Mark & Luke & John \\
    \midrule
  \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
  \endfoot
    \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot}
 {\end{longtable}}
```

Then you'll simply write

```
\begin{mylongtable}{First Ministry in Jerusalem}
<contents>
\end{mylongtable}
```

Comment: I knew it couldn't be too difficult. Thanks for showing me how!